# Show all "title" tooltips at once on one page

Tags: javascript, html

### Thank you for the answers. I edited my question though: I'm trying to show all the tooltips on the page itself. And there are too many `<p>` tags on the page to add a class to them.

I have a page with different "title" attributes.
I know the proper behavior is to show the "title" attribute when you hover your mouse over the element, but i would like to be able to either:

- show all "titles" tooltips at once when I hover one of the divs.
- show all "titles" tooltips at once on page load.

Basic example:

```
 <p title="Correct answer">Hello world</p>
 <p title="Wrong answer">Goodbye world</p>
```

Is there any way i can use JS to show all title attributes at once on my page ?
Note: I need to keep the html title attributes, can't change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

The code belows causes answer-type indicators to appear next to each answer paragraph when you hover over any one of those answer paragraphs. It follows these steps:

- Retrieve all answer paragraphs using `document.querySelectorAll("[titles]")`.
- For each answer paragraph, create a corresponding answer-type indicator div. This div will start out hidden, and will be positioned using `position: absolute`, but that absolute position will be relative to the position of the corresponding original answer paragraph.
- Set up one handler, for the `'mouseover'` event, to make each indicator visible by adding an appropriate "show me" class to it.
- Set up another handler, for the `'mouseout'` event, to make each indicator hidden by removing that same "show me" class from it.

I am being careful not to call these indicators tooltips, as I have noted in the comments. Note, however, that these indicators appear immediately after the hovering starts, but the original default tooltip *for just that particular answer* also appears, just a moment or two later, duplicating some of your display info unnecessarily. You can disable this default tooltip if you want to, but that would take some extra work.

I included `z-index: -1;` in the style of the indicators because of a problem that can occur in its absence. You make the indicators appear by mousing over an answer. However, if, when that indicator appears, it covers the answer where your cursor is located, then the mouse is technically no longer over the answer and you immediately fire the `'mouseout'` event. Alternatively, if you happen to originally mouse-over a position that is on the answer paragraph but a little away from where the indicator appears, the indicator will still appear as expected. However, you only have to move your mouse a few millimeters to mouse-over the indicator, effectively mousing-out of the answer, again causing the indicator to disappear prematurely. The `z-index: -1;` prevents this, as it will ensure that the answer paragraph is also "on top". However, one down side to this is that the indicator text may be partially hidden by the answer text, depending on how you position the indicator relative to the answer text.

```js
// the positioning of each indicator relative its corresponding answer text
var indicOffsetTop = 10;
var indicOffsetLeft = 5;

// retrieve all the answer paragraphs from the DOM
var answers = document.querySelectorAll("[title]");

// build but don't yet show the answer-type indicators

// loop over each answer paragraph
[].forEach.call(answers, function(answer) {
  
  // create a new div element that will contain the answer-type text
  var indic = document.createElement("div");
  
  // style this div so it stands out and also so that it starts out hidden
  indic.classList.add("answerTypeIndicator");
  
  // get the position of the original answer paragraph so that
  // the new answer-type indicator can be positioned near it
  var posn = answer.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // slightly offset the position of the answer-type indicator relative to
  // its corresponding answer text so that both can be seen simultaneously
  indic.style.top = posn.top + indicOffsetTop + "px";
  indic.style.left = posn.left + indicOffsetLeft + "px";
  
  // take the value (i.e. the text) from the title attribute of the answer paragraph
  // and put it into the content of the answer-type indicator
  indic.innerHTML = answer.getAttribute("title");
  
  // place the new indicator into the DOM, but note that it is still hidden at this point
  document.body.appendChild(indic);
});

// put all the newly created answer-type indicator divs into a variable for later access
var indics = document.querySelectorAll(".answerTypeIndicator");

// determine what code to call when starting and stopping hovering over an answer
// do this by adding hover listeners to each "answer" paragraph
[].forEach.call(answers, function(answer) {
  answer.addEventListener("mouseover", showTitleInfo);
  answer.addEventListener("mouseout",  hideTitleInfo);
});

// do this when starting to hover over an answer
function showTitleInfo() {
  
  // loop through each answer-style indicator div
  [].forEach.call(indics, function(indic) {
    
    // make each indicator visible
    indic.classList.add("showing");
  });
}

// do this when stopping hovering over an answer
function hideTitleInfo() {
  
  // loop through each answer-style indicator div
  [].forEach.call(indics, function(indic) {
    
    // hide each indicator
    indic.classList.remove("showing");
  });
}
```

```css
.answerTypeIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: rgba(255, 128, 0, 0.3);
  color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em 0.1em;
  border: solid rgb(200, 0, 0) 1px;
  fill-opacity: 0.2;
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.showing {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h3>Move the mouse over any answer to see all answer types.</h3>
<p>Which of these is a way to greet someone?</p>
<p title="Correct answer">Hello world</p>
<p title="Wrong answer">Goodbye world</p>
<p>What color is an apple?</p>
<p title="Correct answer">Red</p>
<p title="Wrong answer">Blue</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. Any idea of how i can show all the tooltips instead of returning an array with all the "title" attributesin the page ?

Comment: In your question you write that you want to '...show all "titles" tooltips at once when i hover one of the divs...'. A tooltip shows information at or near the location of the cursor. When you hover over a div, do you want it to show just the value of the "title" attribute for that div (e.g. either "Correct answer" **OR** "Wrong answer" from your example, depending on which div you hover over), or do you want it to actually show all "title" attribute values 'at once' as your question states (e.g. both "Correct answer" **AND** "Wrong answer" irrespective of which div you hover over)?

Comment: When i hover over any <p> elements, I want to display all tooltips underneath their respective <p> tags at once. I want each of my <p> tags to have their respective tooltip (with their respective value of the title attribute) displayed. One "title" attribute per tooltip.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the term "tooltip". Check out the [wikipedia Tooltip article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip). With a tooltip, information is shown at or near the cursor location, or at least at or near the element the cursor is hovering over. What you're asking for is just to have the "title" attribute value show up all over the page when any "answer" paragraph is hovered over...a legitimate goal, but that's not a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, check this out.

**HTML:**

```
<p class="display_all_title"></p>
```

**JS:**

```
var all_title = "";

$("body").find('p[title]').each(function() {
    all_title += $(this).attr('title') + " ";
});
$('p.display_all_title').html(all_title);
```

**JsFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/fhepoeb5/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have too many <p> tags on my page to add a class to each of them, would take a long time. Let's say for the purpose of it that i have over 75 <p> tags right now.

Comment: Hi @Ch Hr, if your problem is having many p tags in your page, then you can change the selector to [title] instead of p [title].

Comment: @Ch Hr, note that `class="display_all_title"` is only being added to a single paragraph to show the results, not to each of your so-called "answer" paragraphs.

Comment: @aldrien.h, your jQuery-based solution works. However, it's essentially a waste of effort to put the `$('p.display...` line _inside_ the `.each(...` function, as that will (unnecessarily) update `p.display...` each time through the loop. Better to just move that last line to after the function so that it only updates once at the end. Not a single extra letter of code is required to do that.

Comment: Hi @AndrewWillems , yes I know it. I over looked it haha. Just put the $('p.display_all_title').html(all_title); outside the loop. I will update the answer.