# Is there a way to reveal all the 'hover text' on a webpage at once?

Tags: html, css

I need to compare the hover text tips on a very long web page with that of an older version. I can see the tips in the HTML but there are all run together and and it would help a lot if I could somehow reveal them all on the page at once. Is there any way to do this? I don't own the site I'm trying to do this with so this is not a duplicate of a previous question. In the 'duplicate' question the person asking owns the site - I do not so the 'duplicate' answer cannot help me.

Comment: Hover text as in the text that shows from using the "title" attribute?

Comment: Use dev tools to add the hover state on an element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593746/show-all-title-tooltips-at-once-on-one-page

Comment: They all use this - <a style="cursor:info"> However, I should have mentioned that I don't own or control the website in question

Comment: @user185344 — That's invalid CSS and shouldn't do anything at all.